# How to add sequence for my tasks execution?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dining-philosopher

Sorry for my bad english and thank you very much for your help.

I have a class that starts my tasks :

```
Report report = new Report();


        //Fork to left of Plato and right of Galileo.

        Fork fork1 = new Fork(1, report);
        fork1.m_forkMaterial = fork1.GetRandomMaterial();

        //Fork to left of Confucius and right of Plato.
        Fork fork2 = new Fork(2, report);
        fork2.m_forkMaterial = fork1.GetRandomMaterial();

        //Fork to left of Aristotle and right of Confucius.
        Fork fork3 = new Fork(3, report);
        fork3.m_forkMaterial = fork1.GetRandomMaterial();

        //Fork to left of Socrates and right of Aristotle.
        Fork fork4 = new Fork(4, report);
        fork4.m_forkMaterial = fork1.GetRandomMaterial();

        //Fork to right of Socrates and left of Galileo.
        Fork fork5 = new Fork(5, report);
        fork5.m_forkMaterial = fork1.GetRandomMaterial();

        Task platoTask = new Task(() => new Philosopher.Philosopher("Plato", report, fork1, fork2));
        Task confuciusTask = new Task(() => new Philosopher.Philosopher("Confucius", report, fork2, fork3));
        Task aristotleTask = new Task(() => new Philosopher.Philosopher("Aristotle", report, fork3, fork4));
        Task socratesTask = new Task(() => new Philosopher.Philosopher("Socrates", report, fork4, fork5));
        Task galileoTask = new Task(() => new Philosopher.Philosopher("Galileo", report, fork5, fork1));

        platoTask.Start();
        confuciusTask.Start();
        aristotleTask.Start();  
        socratesTask.Start();
        galileoTask.Start();
```

And now i have a big problem... I've worked very little with tasks and multi threading ...

Question : I need to perform my tasks in a sequence that I will pass to the method (or constructor) 
Like this:

```
College college = new College(1,2,3,4,5); - it's my seq for start tasks.
```

How i can do that? Thank you for help.

Update:
My Philosopher Class:

```
    private Random rng = new Random();
    private Report reportObject;
    private Fork leftFork;
    private Fork rightFork;
    private string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; private set; }

    public Philosopher(string name, Report report, Fork leftFork, Fork rightFork)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.reportObject = report;
        this.leftFork = leftFork;
        this.rightFork = rightFork;
        StateTransition();

    }

    public void StateTransition()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            EnterThinkingState();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            EnterHungryState();
        }
    }



    public void EnterThinkingState()
    {

        Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(1000) + 1);
        Status = "thinking";
        reportObject.ReceiveMessage(Name + " is " + Status);
        Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(1000) + 1);
    }


    public void EnterHungryState()
    {
        Status = "hungry";
        reportObject.ReceiveMessage(Name + " is " + Status);
        bool leftForkTaken = false;
        bool rightForkTaken = false;
        while (!leftForkTaken && !rightForkTaken)
        {
            if (!leftForkTaken)
            {
                Monitor.TryEnter(leftFork, 1000, ref leftForkTaken);
                if (leftForkTaken)
                {
                    leftFork.ForkAction(Name, Fork.ForkActionTypes.kPickUp);
                }
            }
            if (!rightForkTaken)
            {
                Monitor.TryEnter(rightFork, 1000, ref rightForkTaken);
                if (rightForkTaken)
                {
                    rightFork.ForkAction(Name, Fork.ForkActionTypes.kPickUp);
                }
            }
        }
        EnterEatingState();
        Monitor.Exit(leftFork);
        Monitor.Exit(rightFork);
    }


    public void EnterEatingState()
    {
        Status = "eating";
        reportObject.ReceiveMessage(Name + " is " + Status);
        Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(1000) + 1);
        leftFork.ForkAction(Name, Fork.ForkActionTypes.kPutDown);
        rightFork.ForkAction(Name, Fork.ForkActionTypes.kPutDown);
    }
```

My Fork class:

```
public class Fork
{

        private int id;
        private readonly Report _reportObject;

        public enum ForkMaterial
        {
            kSilver = 0,
            kGold = 1
        }

        public enum ForkActionTypes
        {
            kPickUp = 0,
            kPutDown = 1
        }

        public ForkMaterial m_forkMaterial { get; set; }


        public Fork(int id, Report report)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this._reportObject = report;
        }


        public void ForkAction(string name, ForkActionTypes action)
        {
            String actionName = (action == ForkActionTypes.kPickUp) ? " has been picked up by " : " has been put down by ";
            String materialName = (m_forkMaterial == ForkMaterial.kGold) ? "Gold " : "Silver ";

            _reportObject.ReceiveMessage(materialName + "Fork " + id + actionName + name);
        }

        public ForkMaterial GetRandomMaterial()
        {

            Random random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

            int materialNumber = random.Next(100);

            if (materialNumber <= 50)
            {
                return ForkMaterial.kGold;
            }
            else
            {
                return ForkMaterial.kSilver;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you need them in order, it doesnt sound like they need to be tasks, it sounds like you need a list or dictionary and a method that runs them

Comment: Why are you using tasks at all here? They don't do anything. Tasks aren't threads. A Task represents a job that runs asynchronously, possibly on a thread. You never need to create a cold task. In this case though you just call a constructor. You don't need a task for that

Comment: Tasks aren't events either. I suspect you treat tasks like threads and philosophers like workers? Does the `Philosopher` class have an infinite loop that does "something" ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you mean? Why i don't need task for that? I mean... why not?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes. He have. I can update my post .W8 min pls.

Comment: Too much code and comments... This is not "minimum"

Comment: @GianlucaConte okay..sorry. I delete my comments and some useles code..

Comment: @TheGeneral i can't understand what do you mean ? I should use list or dictioanry for runs tasks?

Comment: Why you need tasks when you don't want to execute the codes Simultaneously ? if you want to them in separate thread but with specific order, add theme to queue and execute the queue using one separate task instead of multiple tasks.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik yes.. it's a very strange i know. It's just my..homework? And my teacher say me : Use tasks for this.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Action>` or `List<Action>` or even a switch statement, then you can run your code/methods in any order configurably  (waiting for one to finish to start the next). i think you are over thinking this with tasks

Comment: @MojtabaTajik Philosophers should all eat and think, and they should do this in parallel, because. otherwise they will not have enough forks

Comment: @TheGeneral but how i can change my order config ?

Comment: You cant have them run in order, and also simultaneous, its unclear what you want

Comment: @TheGeneral I need to run my tasks in the order in which I set it by passing it as an argument in the method (or constructor)

Comment: Your teacher must hate you :D. As says @TheGeneral you have two options: simultaneus (using wailAll method) or "wait the current before launch the next" using wait for each task (the last is the same of a synchronous execution)

Comment: If the tasks shares "resources" (such as any variable) the first method is more danger

Comment: @GianlucaConte hm.. you right. Sorry. I have more problems with English than with programming, so I do not understand everything that you are trying to convey to me, and the translator does not do it very well.

Comment: nop. I'll tri to explain this better, but first: have you clear the concept of asynchronous execution?

Comment: @GianlucaConte more yes than no : D

Comment: Ok, so if you execute
var task = Task.Delay(2000);
Dialog.Show("Foo");
You immediatly will see the dialog showing Foo

If you run
var task = Task.Delay(2000);
task.Wait();
Dialog.Show("Foo");

You will wait 2 sec before see the message.
So you must wait each task before start the next.
But they will not run "togheter" (in the same time) (that's not quite exact but it's just to understand).

Comment: If you want to run them at the same time you can use 
 WaitAll that is a method of Task[] type  https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you for help @GianlucaConte